# Stack Snippet editor asking to abandon changes - when none were made

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

I wanted to add an image to a question a minute ago.  I accidentally clicked the snippet button on meta.stackexchange as my eyes went right to it due to its color.  I don't know why but most users associate a colored icon to be that of a picture or photo.  That is why [I asked to change the icon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271551/)

In any event I closed the snippet editor as I realized I did not mean to click that button.  Immediately without any changes (`isDirty=false` :)) closing this popup asked me whether or not I wanted to abandon my changes.  However, I never made any changes so the prompt should not come up.

Comment: +1, drives me *nuts*.